# how can solve deploy material ui icon on vercel

Tags: material-ui, next.js, vercel

i'm trying to deploy my website on vercel, everything is working fine on my localhost3000
but when i try to deploy it on vercel, i keep getting this Error Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material/Github' in '/vercel/path0/components. please why is it not working or do i need to reinstall the material icon package

here is my code

```
import GithubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Github"

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="pb-4">
      <div className="flex justify-center space-x-8 m-3">
        <a href="https://github.com/Emmanueluzoezie"><GithubIcon className="cursor-pointer lg:text-4xl"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: This could be an issue with the build cache, or with your lockfile. You could try regenerating your lockfile, or overriding the build cache on deployment. 

https://vercel.com/docs/cli#options/global-options/force

Answer (score 0):

the h in the github was uppercase not smallercase

this is what i was using

```
import GithubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Github"
```

instead of this

```
import GitHubIcon from "@mui/icons-material/GitHub"
```